# How can I show a block only on the edit page for a specific content type?

Tags: blocks

I have a block that I would like to display on the edit page for a specific content type.  Since the content of this block describes the site policy for editing that specific content type, I only want users to see it when editing nodes of that content type.

I tried setting the block display path to `node/*/edit*` and checking the appropriate content type on the block display menu, but that didn't work.

Comment: I know it sounds simple, but I though I'd best check - are you setting the block visibility on the correct theme?

Comment: @Chapabu Yes, but a check of the block settings led me to find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the source of the problem: the block was set to the wrong language, so I wasn't able to see it even though the path (`node/*/edit*`) was correct.  Setting the block to the correct language allowed me to use the path `node/*/edit*`.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement [hook_block_list_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_list_alter/7) to alter the status of the block. (Replace `$bid` with the block ID, and `$content_type` with the content type you are interested to.)

```
function mymodule_block_list_alter(&$blocks) {
  if (!empty($blocks[$bid]) && ($node = menu_get_object()) && arg(2) == 'edit' && $node->type == $content_type) {
    $blocks[$bid]->status = 1;
  }
}
```